# How can I use the BigQuery REST API from the command line?

Tags: rest, command-line, google-bigquery

Attempting to make a plain GET request to one of the BigQuery REST APIs gives an error that looks like this:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs/$JOBID
```

Output:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization",
  ...
```

What is the correct way to invoke one of the REST APIs from the command-line, such as the `query` or `insert` APIs? The [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) has a "Try this API", but the examples don't translate directly to something you can run from the command-line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a disclaimer, when working from the command-line, using the `bq` tool will usually be sufficient, or for more complex use cases, the [BigQuery client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) enable programming with BigQuery from multiple languages. It can still be useful sometimes to make plain requests to the REST APIs to see how certain APIs work at a low level, however.

First, make sure that you have [installed the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/). This should include the `gcloud` and `bq` command-line tools. If you haven't already, authorize your account by running this command from your terminal:

```
gcloud auth login
```

This should prompt you to log in and then give you an access code that you can paste into your terminal. (The exact process may change over time).

Now let's try a query using the BigQuery REST API, calling the [`jobs.query` method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query). Modify this script with your own project name, which you can find from [the Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), then paste the script into your terminal:

```
PROJECT="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
QUERY="\"SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y;\""
REQUEST="{\"kind\":\"bigquery#queryRequest\",\"useLegacySql\":false,\"query\":$QUERY}"
echo $REQUEST | \
  curl -X POST -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/queries
```

If it worked, you should see output that looks like this:

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "x",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "y",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
 },
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "<your project ID>",
  "jobId": "<your job ID>"
 },
 "totalRows": "1",
 "rows": [
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "1"
    },
    {
     "v": "foo"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": false
}
```

If you haven't set up the `bq` command-line tool, you can use `bq init` from your terminal to do so. Once you have, you can try running the same query using it:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False "SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y;"
```

You can also see the REST API requests that the `bq` tool makes by passing the `--apilog=` option:

```
bq --apilog= query --use_legacy_sql=False "SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS x;"
```

Now let's try an example using the [`jobs.insert` method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) instead of the `query` API. Run this script, replacing `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` with your project name:

```
PROJECT="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
QUERY="\"SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y;\""
REQUEST="{\"configuration\":{\"query\":{\"useLegacySql\":false,\"query\":${QUERY}}}}"
echo $REQUEST | \
curl -X POST -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/jobs
```

Unlike the `query` API, which returned a response immediately, you will see a result that looks similar to this:

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#job",
 "etag": "\"<etag string>\"",
 "id": "<project name>:<job ID>",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project name>/jobs/<job ID>",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "<project name>",
  "jobId": "<job ID>"
 },
 "configuration": {
  "query": {
   "query": "SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y;",
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": "<project name>",
    "datasetId": "<anonymous dataset>",
    "tableId": "<anonymous table>"
   },
   "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
   "useLegacySql": false
  }
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "RUNNING"
 },
 "statistics": {
  "creationTime": "<timestamp millis>",
  "startTime": "<timestamp millis>"
 },
 "user_email": "<your email address>"
}
```

Notice the status:

```
 "status": {
  "state": "RUNNING"
 },
```

If you want to check on the job now, you can use the [`jobs.get` method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get). Similar to before, run this from your terminal, using the job ID from the output in the previous step:

```
PROJECT="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
JOB_ID="YOUR_JOB_ID"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/jobs/$JOB_ID
```

If the query is done, you'll get a response that indicates as much:

```
...
"status": {
 "state": "DONE"
},
...
```

Finally, we can make a request to fetch the query results, also using the REST API.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/queries/$JOB_ID
```

The output will look similar to when we used the `jobs.query` method above:

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#getQueryResultsResponse",
 "etag": "\"<etag string>\"",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "x",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "y",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
 },
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "<project ID>",
  "jobId": "<job ID>"
 },
 "totalRows": "1",
 "rows": [
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "1"
    },
    {
     "v": "foo"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": true
}
```