# Use BigQuery REST or Java API to run query to get JSON output format

Tags: java, json, rest, api, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use [google-cloud API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery) to run a query against a table and get the result in JSON format. So far I've explored the following solutions, but none is satisfactory:

- Modify the SQL by using `TO_JSON_STRING` function. It has to modify the original SQL. And the JSON format is different than the JSON format used when exporting a table.
- Use the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) but I have yet to find the document related to supporting JSON output format.
- I found the BigQuery command supports querying data and resulting in JSON format as in `bq query --format json --project_id myProject "select * from sandbox.keweiquerytable"`. So I naturally think it should call a REST API behind the scene. But how can I find the related REST API?

Comment: Have you seen this question? It walks through using `curl` to get query results as JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108038/how-can-i-use-the-bigquery-rest-api-from-the-command-line. You can make a POST request from Java code instead of using `curl`.

Comment: Thanks. Making a REST call will get a more "general" output in JSON format. But not a JSON representation of the rows. I'd expect something like the following (same JSON in bigquery web ui, or in `bq` command):

The `bq query --format json --project_id my-test-project "select * from sandbox.employees"` would get the following result 
`[{"employee":"peter","age":"40"},{"employee":"john","age":"30"},{"employee":"jack","age":"50"},{"employee":"michael","age":"20"},{"employee":"eric","age":"60"}]`

Comment: You would need to perform that transformation yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly, I can use both low-level REST API, or high-level BigQuery client libraries. But whichever solution I choose, I have to transform the query response manually to get the same JSON format as in web ui / export such as: `[{"employee":"peter","age":"40"}, ...]`. For now, there is no native support for such transformation, apart from using `TO_JSON_STRING` function. The `bq query --format json ...` tool uses REST API behind the scene but its' python implementation transforms "manually" the REST response to the json output we see  `[{"employee":"peter","age":"40"}]`

Comment: That sounds right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, we have 2 possible solutions:

1. Use `TO_JSON_STRING` function to get directly the query result in JSON representation of rows, as in `[{"employee":"peter","age":"40"},{"employee":"john","age":"3‌​0"},{"employee":"jac‌​k","age":"50"},{"emp‌​loyee":"michael","ag‌​e":"20"},{"employee"‌​:"eric","age":"60"}]`
2. Use high-level BigQuery client libraries, or low-level REST API, but then we have to perform the transformation to JSON ourselves.