# how to add `maximumBillingTier` to query

Tags: google-bigquery

here is is in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery), but where do I add it to the query?

```
curl  -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <your_oauth2_token>" -H "Content-Length: 8" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/queries' \
-d "{ 
  timeoutMs: 600000,
  queryParameters: [],
  query:
   'SELECT * FROM [my-project:Views.TEST_11]',
  maxResults: 0,
  kind: 'bigquery#queryRequest'
}
"
```

is it part of the body?

```
-d "{
  ...
  ..
  maximumBillingTier: '2',
"
```

it does not seem to be part of the [QueryRequest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest) body

Comment: I think you'd have to use the jobs.insert API instead (but I'm not clear why you need to set this property in the first place). It also looks like you're using legacy SQL, but it would be good to use standard SQL if you can since it tends to be less resource intensive.

Comment: where can I find a `curl` example to convert above query to `insert` job?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108039/6253347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use jobs.query API; however, this uses the object [QueryRequest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest) which doesn't have the maximumBillingTier option, to use this option you should to use the [jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) API instead.

The body for jobs.insert should look like this:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "Select * from mydataset.mytable",
      "maximumBillingTier": 1
    }
  }
}
```